# how session works online

Tags: php, session

Does `session_destroy()` affect different users?
Imagine a situation where there are two users on the same site and the first one gets to the point in the code where `session_destroy()` is called. Does that destroy all session data on the site (even for the second user)?

Comment: I would look into `session_unset()` also http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php and going through **User Contributed Notes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_destroy()` will **only** affect one user with this session.

a Quick explanation how session works for a user.

A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages.

Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer.

When a session is started following things happen

- PHP first creates a unique identifier (a random string of 32 hexadecimal numbers)
- A cookie called PHPSESSID is automatically sent to the user's computer to store unique session identification string.
- A file is automatically created on the server in the designated temporary directory and bears the name of the unique identifier

and a session ends when the user *loses* the browser or after leaving the page.

For more information see: [session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Answer (score 1):

A 'session` is by definition per user, so no, Destroying a session for user 1 has no affect on user 2